# gsutil cp: copy files with -I option to matching subdirectories

Tags: gsutil

I would like to copy a list of files to a bucket while keeping the directory-structure.

test.txt:

```
a/b/1.jpg
a/c/23.jpg
a/d/145.jpg
```

gsutil command:

```
cat file.txt | gsutil -m cp -I 'gs://my-bucket/'
```

This copies the files but ignores the subdirectories. Is there a way to solve my problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question because i had a very similar case. There still isn't a great way to do that, but i recently found [this tip](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/465#issuecomment-632698470) which allows to use gsutil rsync and hack -x flag to act as inclusion rather than exclusion by adding negative lookahead.

For example, below would copy all json files found in any subdirectory of current directory, while preserving their paths in a bucket

```
gsutil -m rsync -r -x '^(?!.*\.json$).*' . gs://mybucket
```

This can be further adjusted to include multiple entries. For example, this command would copy all found json, yaml and yml files

```
gsutil -m rsync -r -x '^(?!.*\.(json|yaml|yml)$).*' . gs://mybucket
```

By itself this is not very useful for a case, where you have specified file list, but let's work on it. Let's use youtube-dl repo (https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl.git) as an example.

Let's take all md files from the repo and pretend they are our specified file list. Last file is in a subpath

```
find * -name "*.md"
CONTRIBUTING.md
README.md
docs/supportedsites.md
```

We use * to [remove leading dots from the names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537241) to require less processing

```
# Read file paths into var
# For file with path list, use
# cat file|read -d '' flist
find * -name "*.md"|read -d '' flist

# Concat paths into what gsutil accepts as a file list in -x parameter
rx="^(?\!($(echo $flist|tr '\n' '|')$)).*"

# Preview rx variable (just for clarity)
echo $rx
^(?!(CONTRIBUTING.md|README.md|docs/supportedsites.md|$)).*

# Run sync in dry mode
gsutil -m rsync -n -r -x $rx . gs://mybucket
...
Would copy file://./CONTRIBUTING.md to gs://mybucket/CONTRIBUTING.md
Would copy file://./README.md to gs://mybucket/README.md
Would copy file://./docs/supportedsites.md to gs://mybucket/docs/supportedsites.md
```

While a little involved, it does allow use of -m flag for speed while preserving paths.

With some more processing it should be very possible to

- remove empty newline from `find` result
- handle paths beginning with `./`

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and after some thoughts, I figured that it is by design just like unix `cp` command. I came up with a solution using `xargs` utility and you can do:

```
cat test.txt | xargs -I '{}' gsutil '{}' gs://my-bucket-name/'{}'
```

With `-I` option, xargs executes the following command for each input line. One downside this method introduces is that you can't use `-m` for `gsutil cp` which can significantly slows down the task.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the -R option to get recursive copy:
`gsutil -m cp -R gs://my-bucket/`

From the documetation:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

> If you want to copy an entire directory tree you need to use the -r option:
>   `gsutil cp -r dir gs://my-bucket`

Hope that helps!

Comment: alas, what `-r` does is copy the tree of a specified directory to a target, not any intervening directories for a specified file.  Effectively, `gsutil cp` has no idea about a "root"/"working" directory for the source.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `find` command instead. For example, the following command helped me to copy all .json file under "[you path]" folder and its subfolders into a GCS bucket, with the -m option working. Hope it helps

```
sudo find [your path] -print | grep -i '.*[.]json' | sudo gsutil -m cp -I gs://[your bucket]
```